# Get block file size on MacOs with statfs

Tags: c++, macos, filesystems

I want to find out what is block file size under MacOs. In my example I try to determine /dev/disk0:

```
diskutil info /dev/disk0
   Device Identifier:         disk0
   Device Node:               /dev/disk0
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk0
   Device / Media Name:       APPLE SSD SD0128F

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI
   SMART Status:              Verified

   Disk Size:                 121.3 GB (121332826112 Bytes) (exactly 236978176 512-Byte-Units)
```

Diskutil gives correct size "123.3 GB". Now the same thing using statfs:(https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/statfs.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/statfs):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>

int main()
{
        struct statfs s;
        statfs("/dev/disk0", &s);
        std::cout << s.f_bsize * s.f_blocks << " B\n";
}
```

Output: 196096 B

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of `statfs` is as follows:

> Statfs() returns information about a mounted file system.  Path is the
>        path name of any file within the mounted file system.  Buf is a pointer
>        to a statfs or statfs64 structure defined as follows...

You are passing `/dev/disk0` as the path, which will give you the size of whatever filesystem represents `/dev`, which is likely some sort of devtmpfs. Your path should be a filename or path within the filesystem held on `/dev/disk0`, not the block device itself.

### For an arbitrary block device:

Issue IOCTLs [as documented](http://newosxbook.com/src.jl?tree=&file=/xnu-2782.40.9/bsd/sys/disk.h):

```
int fd = open("/dev/whatever", O_RDONLY);
if(fd  < 0) {
    // error handling
}
uint64_t count;
if(ioctl(fd, DKIOCGETBLOCKCOUNT, &count) < 0) {
    // error handling
}
uint32_t bsize;
if(ioctl(fd, DKIOCGETBLOCKSIZE, &bsize) < 0) {
    // error handling
}
return count * bsize;
```

Comment: Ok how to get that path?

Comment: @MateuszWojtczak If this disk represents the filesystem root, `/` ought to work.

Comment: @MateuszWojtczak Your question is not clear. If you are looking for the size of the root partition, you just use the literal `"/"`. If you want to get the size of an arbitrary block device with an unknown mount point, you can walk through the mount table with `getmtent`. If you want to get the size of an arbitrary, not necessarily mounted, block device, you'll need to issue the `BLKGETSIZE64` IOCTL. Again, you will run into weird awkwardness since it might not be mounted, might be mounted with a file system that reserves space, etc.

Comment: `getfsstat` will return an array of `statfs` structures.

Comment: @nanofarad I want to get size arbitrary block file. I don't see getmtent on macOs I assume this is linux specific. What is the MacOs equivalent?

Comment: @MateuszWojtczak If you want to get the size of an arbitrary block device, just issue the `BLKGETSIZE64` IOCTL against that device. There's no reason to needlessly tie filesystem code into it, since a block device does not necessarily have a file system.

Comment: @nanofarad I don't see BLKGETSIZE64 defined under mac os, I assume this is linux specific also.

Comment: @MateuszWojtczak It looks like Apple defines it as `DIOCGMEDIASIZE` (from freebsd) taking an `off_t`. Edit, no, Apple does something even more different for some reason. Answer being edited rn

Comment: This just gives me operation not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the original question is weird. Since as nanofarad already stated that we should pass `statfs` with the path name of any file or directory within the mounted file system instead of the device's bsdname(like /dev/disk1s1).

I saw the the question from Matt:

> A way to get the block or "fragment" size for the device on a given path
> is on (usually from statfs on Linux, but relevant fields seem to be
> missing on Darwin?).

I presume you are asking "Given a file path, how to get the block size of its physical device?"

Well if so, macOS has a high-level API for this. It's the `DiskArbitration` framework.

It has a function `DADiskCreateFromVolumePath` which can get Disk object from any path. [Apple Document Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/diskarbitration/1401858-dadiskcreatefromvolumepath)

So to get the block size for the device on a given path is on, you can use below code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <DiskArbitration/DADisk.h> //Import DiskArbitration.framework&CoreFoundation.framework in xcode first
#include <DiskArbitration/DASession.h>


#define PATH "/"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  //Create DASession
  DASessionRef session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

  //Create URL from file path
  CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                             CFSTR(PATH),
                                             kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle,
                                             true);
  //Get path's physical disk
  DADiskRef diskRef = DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                               session,
                                               url);
  //Acquire all disk info, see the screenshot below.
  CFDictionaryRef infoRef = DADiskCopyDescription(diskRef);


}
```

and below is all the info I get from the build-in apfs disk partition:

[image]

It has a device block size of 4096 bytes.

Comment: I don't think this takes a file path, you need to figure out the specific device first. The disk description only contains the block size, I didn't see a fragment or even segment size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total size of the device, try this :

```
// gcc -Wall -framework Foundation -framework DiskArbitration disk_size.m -o disk_size
// Call method : ./disk_size /dev/disk0
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    DASessionRef session = DASessionCreate(NULL);

    DADiskRef disk = DADiskCreateFromBSDName(NULL, session, argv[1]);

    CFDictionaryRef diskDescription = DADiskCopyDescription(disk);
    NSDictionary *diskData = (NSDictionary *)diskDescription;
    NSString *diskSizeKey = (NSString *)kDADiskDescriptionMediaSizeKey;
    unsigned long size = [[diskData objectForKey:diskSizeKey] unsignedLongValue];
    NSLog(@"size in bytes = %lu", size);

    CFRelease(diskDescription);
    CFRelease(disk);
    CFRelease(session);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Your example extracts the disk size, not the block or fragment size. That said I was able to use your example to log the contents of the disk description.